# How good is QuartzCode at converting animations into Objective-C or Swift code

Tags: objective-c, swift, quartzcode

I assume this is the best community to get feedback from iOS developers. If not please let me know.

Today I came across this software: [QuartzCode](http://www.quartzcodeapp.com/).

I am wondering how good it is at converting animations you've created into Objective-C or Swift code? Does anyone have firsthand experience?

I am only new to programming and Swift is the first language I'm learning, so I thought this may be a useful tool, especially since I can already see I will need to learn Objective-C as well.

I did a search but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty good! I use it regularly at my workplace + [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com) (**really** good too). I recommend both.

While PaintCode focus more on "static" images (although you can also use it to create nice little animations), QuartzCode provides a powerful canvas to build almost any type of composition.

Here are some very simple examples on creating custom UIRefreshControl elements with QuartzCode:

**Example 01**
[image: Demo 1]

**Example 02**
[image: Demo 2]

**Example 03**
[image: Demo 3]

It took me 2 hours or so. QuartzCode == timesaving.

Here is [a video of the entire thing](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/0n1j0v0r2o0k2f0m0B0A/CustomPullDownToRefresh.mp4).

And [here is the Github project](https://github.com/backslash-f/quartzcode-uirefreshcontrol) (with [the QuartzCode file](https://github.com/backslash-f/quartzcode-uirefreshcontrol/blob/master/QuartzCode-Project/CloudAnimation.qc)).

Don't mind all the boilerplate code in that TableViewController...
The most important part starts at line 144:

```
/// Animates the cloud up and down.
private func animateCloudUpAndDown() {
    customUIRefreshControl.addRefreshUpDownAnimation()
}

/// "Draws" the cloud by make its stroke line gradually visible, then shows
/// a solid blueish background and then fades everything out.
private func animateCloudStrokeWithGradientFill() {
    customUIRefreshControl.addRefreshGradientAnimation()
}

/// "Draws" the cloud by make its stroke line gradually visible, then shows
/// a gradient blueish background and then fades everything out.
private func animateCloudStrokeWithSolidFill() {
    customUIRefreshControl.addRefreshSolidAnimation()
}
```

One liner code to start the animations created in QuartzCode. It's THAT simple. :)

Comment: Do you mean that it took you 2 hours to create the animation in QuartzCode? I'm considering using this in my own application.

Comment: Yes. And I'm a software developer, not a designer (I did fool around with Adobe Flash years ago, so I'm familiar with the "timeline" concept -- but that's all). There is a free trial in QuarzCode site, try it out. ;) http://www.quartzcodeapp.com/?smd_process_download=1&download_id=869

Answer (score 1):

Quartz 2D is an apple framework used for drawing path-based drawing, painting with transparency,color management etc.

Its quite powerful and makes use of GPU hardware also it is a stepping stone to learn 3D and 2D animations with Open Gl

However if you are newComer to iOS i would suggest you to first go through
Core Animations and Core Graphics(which includes QuartzCode... )and then jump to Quartz 2D api. That would help u understand the concepts better

[HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_GraphicsImaging/_index.html) This is the best reference on the net you can find.. if u want to know about all graphic technologies and where to start.

if you want to search the library [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html) page will be good enough.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've had a look and there's a lot of info there, including sample code. In terms of the QuartzCode app itself, do you know how good it is? I am wondering whether it's worth purchasing?

Comment: I havent used that app so no comments.
However if you do not want urself to be limited by the limitations of the app. 
Then it would be good to learn to use quartz 2D yourself.
It will help you have a better control over your animations

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was thinking that since the app is supposed to generate code for both Swift and Objective-C then I could compare the code and modify it within Xcode, and that it would be a useful learning tool in that way. But I also understand that approach could backfire, especially if the code it generates is rather verbose compared to what one may be able write themselves. Something for me to ponder.

Comment: i am working on core animations too and beleive me at some point of time it will surely backfire... You wont have the basics right if you do it this way.
I will provide you with some more links in the chat.

Comment: Sorry, after posting my last comment I went straight to a meeting and missed the chat.